# How to correctly implement android Lifecycle with the architecture component

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm new to architecture component, I have created a ViewModel class and implemented LifecycleObserver as per the architecture component, inside the ViewModel class i have a overriden run() method of runnable interface and call it recursively with delay by the help of handler class, inside this value images array changes and wrapped by the live data.

MainActivity observe the changes of the images array and as the value changes, ImageView binds the value of images array.Main activity is also the lifecycle owner.

Now i want to implement Lifecycle observer, so that when i pause my application run() method should also pause and when i resume the application it start from where i pause.

I tried it by creating pause and resume method in the handler, but it didn't work.

Help me with this.

**MainActivity Class**

```
private ImageViewModel imageViewModel;

private ImageView imageView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showDialogueBox();
}

private void showDialogueBox() {
    final Dialog dialog  =  new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogue_box);
    dialog.setTitle("custom");
    Button button =(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setEnabled(true);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this).get(ImageViewModel.class);
            subscribe();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

private void subscribe() {
    final Observer<Integer> imageTimeObserver = new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
            imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(integer);
            getLifecycle().addObserver(new BrainalyseComponent(MainActivity.this,getApplicationContext(),imageViewModel));
        }
    };

    final Observer<Integer> progressbarTimeObserver = new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setProgress(integer);
        }
    };

    imageViewModel.getImage().observe(this,imageTimeObserver);
    imageViewModel.getProgressbarStatus().observe(this,progressbarTimeObserver);
}
```

**ViewModel class**

```
private int imagesIndex;
private int delay;
public Handler handler;
private MutableLiveData<Integer> imageLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
private MutableLiveData<Integer> progressbarLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
private int progressBarStatus;
private HashMap<Integer,Integer> imagesAndDelay;
private int images[] =
        {
                R.drawable.food_1,
                R.drawable.food_2,
                R.drawable.food_3,
                R.drawable.food_4,
                R.drawable.food_5,
                R.drawable.food_6,
                R.drawable.food_7,
                R.drawable.food_8,
                R.drawable.food_9,
                R.drawable.food_10
        };


public ImageViewModel(){
    imagesIndex = 0;
    progressBarStatus = 0;
    delay = 2;//to be changed as delay will be discussed

    handler = new Handler();
    imagesAndDelay = new HashMap<>();

    shuffleImages();
    runnable.run();

}



private void shuffleImages() {
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        int j = random.nextInt(images.length);
        int temp = images[i];
        images[i] = images[j];
        images[j] = temp;
    }
}



public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (imagesIndex<images.length){
            progressBarStatus += 100/images.length;

            progressbarLiveData.postValue(progressBarStatus);
            imageLiveData.postValue(images[imagesIndex]);

            imagesAndDelay.put(images[imagesIndex],delay);

            imagesIndex++;
            delay += 2;
        }else {
            stopTask();
            return;
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,2000);
    }
};


public Thread newThread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        if (imagesIndex<images.length){
            progressBarStatus += 100/images.length;

            progressbarLiveData.postValue(progressBarStatus);
            imageLiveData.postValue(images[imagesIndex]);

            imagesAndDelay.put(images[imagesIndex],delay);

            imagesIndex++;
            delay += 2;
        }else {
            stopTask();
            return;
        }
        try {
            sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            run();
        }
    }
};




public LiveData<Integer> getImage(){
    return imageLiveData;
}

public LiveData<Integer> getProgressbarStatus(){
    return progressbarLiveData;
}


private void stopTask() {
    delay = 2; 
    progressBarStatus = 0;
    imagesIndex = 0;
    Utility.setImagesAndDelay(imagesAndDelay);
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

}
```

**LifecycleObsever**

```
private Context mContext;
private static final String LOG_TAG = BrainalyseComponent.class.getSimpleName();
private ImageView imageView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Integer integer;
LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner;
private ImageViewModel imageViewModel;
public BrainalyseComponent(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner, Context context, ImageViewModel imageViewModel) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.imageView = imageView;
    this.imageViewModel = imageViewModel;
    this.integer = integer;
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner;
}





@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
public void onResume(){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"on resume of app");
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
public void onPause(){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing listener and you'll need to remove it at some point (from onDestroy for example)

```
public BrainalyseComponent(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner, Context context, ImageViewModel imageViewModel) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.imageView = imageView;
    this.imageViewModel = imageViewModel;
    this.integer = integer;
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner;
    lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
public void onDestroy(){
    lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);
}
```

Comment: I need to pause the runnable interface when app enters into to the pause state and resume it from where it was paused when app enters into the resume state. @Samuel Eminet